# How do you insert arrays into a state variable of a nested array? - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a state variable like this:

`const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])`

I want to put a lot of arrays into it (in an amount unknown to me).
This is the code I wrote:

```
data.forEach(x => {
           const userId = x.userId;
           const to_to_user = data.filter(d=>d.userId===userId)
           setTodos({...todos, [userId]:to_to_user});
           });
```

The problem is that each round of a loop overruns the previous index and at the end of the array there is only the last index.
Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, you can do this:

```js
data.forEach(x => {
  const userId = x.userId;
  const to_to_user = data.filter(d=>d.userId===userId)
  setTodos((oldTodos) => {...oldTodos, [userId]:to_to_user}));
});
```

so that you always have the most up-to-date version of `todos`.

But instead of calling `setTodos` multiple times, you should instead create the object first and then call `setTodos` once.

```js
const newTodos = data.reduce((obj, x) => {
  const userId = x.userId;
  const to_to_user = data.filter(d=>d.userId===userId);
  obj[userId] = to_to_user;
}, {});

setTodos((oldTodos) => {...oldTodos, ...newTodos});
```

Either way, the original line should be

```js
const [todos, setTodos] = useState({});
```

because you're storing an object of arrays, not an array of objects or and array of arrays

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
What is `obj`? What does he represent to me?

Comment: `obj` is short for `object`. Just a generic name like `key` and `val` (value) that I use when there's not really a good name to use there.

Comment: Yes, I understood that it is short for `object`, but I didn't understand, is it an array? object? I get an error like this:
`main.js:26 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '0')
    at main.js:26:1
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at main.js:23:1`

Comment: It turns out that the problem was in the `obj` name... I changed `obj1` and everything worked out. Thank you for your quick response!